# Have they really escaped from Alcatraz?

Tags: plot-explanation, historical-accuracy, escape-from-alcatraz

In [Escape from Alcatraz](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079116/), nobody had ever escaped from Alcatraz prison, and Frank with two friends tried to escape. However, at the end of the film, we never know if they survived or if they drowned in the sea.

There is information in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_from_Alcatraz_%28film%29#Background_and_historical_accuracy);

> While it is not known whether the three escapees survived, sightings
>   of them over the years provides circumstantial evidence that they may
>   have.

Is there any information about whether they survived or not other than this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to all-knowing [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Morris_%28prisoner%29) (smile):

> In the end, authorities pointed out that the chances of the prisoners
>   surviving the trip across the bay were slim. At the time, there was no
>   discovery of robberies or car thefts that could have been attributed
>   to them, and the men were habitual criminals yet were never arrested
>   again. The FBI officially closed the case on December 31, 1979,
>   concluding that "no credible evidence emerged to suggest the men were
>   still alive" (though there have been many subsequent reconstructions
>   and yearly triathlon events are held to commemorate the event). There
>   have been sightings of the three men over the years which provides
>   circumstantial evidence that they might have survived. If Morris did
>   survive the escape and is still alive today, he would be 86 years
>   old.

In this video on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=9W7coNTryV0), his cousin Bud Morris says he helped finance the escape and he saw Frank after the escape.

According to this [article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/tom-cochran/frank-morris-escape-alcatraz_b_1872290.html), the case was reopened in 1993:

> The official position of the marshals service is that the inmates
>   likely drowned in their attempt, however, their spokesman, Dave
>   Branham was quoted as saying, “we think there is a possibility they
>   are alive.”

The article also claims:

> The following day, a search party found the remains of the raincoat
>   raft on Angel Island, two miles north of Alcatraz. Along with the raft
>   was discovered a small plastic bag containing the personal effects of
>   the Anglins.
>
> To further add to the mystery, footsteps were seen heading away from
>   the raft on the beach.

And this totally reliable account from [mafiatoday.com](http://mafiatoday.com/general-breaking-news/breaking-news-frank-morris-alcatraz-escapee-found-living-in-ireland/) claims to have interviewed him:

> Frank Morris the most famous convict ever to escape from Alcatraz
>   prison and who was presumed to have drowned by authorities has been
>   found to be living under the assumed name of Padraic Welsh in a remote
>   part of Connemara on the western coast of Ireland.
>
> Frank now 83 years of age decided the time was right to break the
>   silence and put the record straight after 47 years living a tranquil
>   life in a remote part of the west of Ireland. Recounting the night of
>   June 11, 1962, Frank said the escape went ahead as planned and along
>   with fellow escapees brothers John and Clarence Anglin they placed the
>   dummies in their beds, escaped through the vents at the back of their
>   cells and into the utility corridor. They then proceeded onto the roof
>   and down to the bay. There they boarded the raft they had constructed
>   and disappeared into the night to rendezvous with a boat which they
>   had arranged to pick them up, they then destroyed the raft and
>   scattered personal belonging into the bay to throw the authoritys off
>   their trail.
>
> Frank having relatives from the west of Ireland and an aunt living in
>   Connemara had already organised passage to the Emerald Isle prior to
>   escaping as for John and Clarence Anglin he never heard from them
>   since and often wonders what became of them.

I think you have to choose what you believe.